# How to set API relative with page in nextjs?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I wondering how to set API pathname belong to pages.

My folder structure is:

```
src                                  
 ├── component        
 │     ├── common      
 │     └── layout            
 │            
 │                        
 │              
 ├── pages              
 │    ├── todo
 │    │    ├── index.js
 │    │    ├── list
 │    │          ├── index.js
 │    │
 │    ├── counter
 │
 ├── api  
 │     ├── user          
 │     ├── list           
 │
```

I want to make API call
"localhost:3000/todo/api/...","localhost:3000/counter/api/.." not "localhost:3000/api/todo"

Any help or guidance on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Next.js [API routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) have to be located under the `/pages/api` folder. You could then setup [`rewrites`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) in the `next.config.js` to map the desired paths to the expected routes within the `api` folder. For example: `{ source: '/:path/api', destination: '/api/:path' }`.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible.
The api folder helps nextjs processing queries and understanding where is the backend and where is the frontend.

Easiest way is creating different pages in your api folder (api/todo and api/counter).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).